# JavaScript Class Variable Assignment - What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, oop, class

What is wrong with this assignment?

```
base = {};
base.util = {
   varA : 3,
   varB : this.varA,
   show : function(){
      console.log(this.varB);
   }
};
```

am getting this.varB is undefined. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In this example, `this` is referring to the global `window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare literals, the value of `this` will only be your object when inside a method. Otherwise, its value will depend on the context where the literal is declared.

To accomplish what you want, you have to code it like this:

```
base = {};
base.util = {
   varA : 3,
   show : function(){
      // here, this refers to base.util
      console.log(this.varB);
   }
};
base.util.varB = base.util.varA;
base.util.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the shorthand for creating objects, `this` is in the global scope and thus refers to `window`. Try checking if `window.varA` or just `varA` is defined after you create the object.